# How do I switch between two different widgets on the same location in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a card widget which has some info and a button. On button press, I want to animate the card to change to a different card at the same location. The animation will be added later.

As per my current code, I am using a bool to control which widget to display.

My card1 has the following code-

```
SliverFillRemaining(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10.0, left: 6.0, right: 6.0, bottom: 6.0),
        child: detailsCardIsVisible ? Card(
            elevation: 2.0,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
            child: productInfoCard()) : ProductEnquiryWidget()
      ),
    )
```

The ProductEnquiryWidget is the second card. It has a form with a button. What I want to do is to submit the form on button press and animate back to the first card.

How do I do that? I don't want to put the code for the second card in the same file as the first card as it will make the code too large.

I am using a boolean named **detailsCardIsVisible** to control which card to display. Is there a way I could manipulate that variable from button tap in the second card?

Comment: Use `StatefulWidget` and change your bool variable value when click on the card using `setState()`. Then display relevant card according to that bool variable

Comment: The issue is that the 2 widgets are in different files. I don't want to merge them into one. So, when, I click the button in the 2nd widget, it should change the bool in the first widget which is in a different file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html

```
AnimatedCrossFade(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
  firstChild: FirstChild(),
  secondChild: SecondChild(),
  crossFadeState: _first ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
)
```

Comment: I haven't tried it but I see a possible issue. The 2nd widget is in a different file. How do I change the boolean in a file by button tap in a different file?

Comment: I don't understand why it would matter what file it is in. Perhaps you want to go through https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

Comment: As per the docs of AnimatedCrossFade, the variable _first shows the firstChild when it is true and the other when false. Now, assuming that in file1, I use this ACF to show firstChild and on button press, I change _first to false. It will now draw the secondChild from another class. On a button press in the secondChild, I want to draw the firstChild again. To do that, I must set _first to true. I still don't see how will I access the _first from  firstChild class in the secondChild class.

Comment: Forgive me if the answer is clear but I am not able to understand it.

Comment: You need proper state management where the state is managed outside the widget tree but accessible to the widget that needs access to it. I suggest again to go through the link I posted before.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is the only way

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to animate, you can use Visibility:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

It takes a `replacement` Widget that's displayed when `visible` is false.